# How to get kafka brokers status using JMX

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx

Is there any option to get the status of the kafka brokers using JMX?
If so, what metric should I query?
Or maybe I can extrapolate from other metrics ?
Thanks,
Rudi

Comment: What kind of status are you looking for? If the broker process is down, then JMX would be unavailable

Comment: Basically,I need to know if the brokers are up, so I can know if the service is up (for my dashboard)
I am running my kafka cluster on VM's.
It seems clumsy to query each broker.Im looking for a metric (or any other method)  which will show me how many brokers are in running status, without querying each broker

Comment: As mentioned, JMX wouldn't be available if the broker JVM stops, so any metric would work, but sounds like you want a local process healthcheck, for example using a Consul, Nagios, or Zabbix agent on the broker